# How do I count the number of matches that have the same position between two vectors?

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of matches between two vectors: `c(1,2,1)` and `c(2,2,2)` with the goal of returning `1`. only the second position matches between both vectors. Every solution I come up with has a loop in it though. Can someone suggest an R function to do this, rather than a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have equal length vectors, you can use `==` to determine  the matches.

```
c(1, 2, 1) == c(2, 2, 2)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now, since the numeric representations of `TRUE` and `FALSE` are 1 and 0 respectively, the sum of the result will give the number of matches.

```
sum(c(1, 2, 1) == c(2, 2, 2))
# [1] 1
```